# C++: Why Does It Output On Alternative Basis?

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

Consider the following C++ code: (codeblocks = IDE)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;
    while(cin>>a) {
        cout<<"You sir, Just Entered: "<<a<<endl;
        if(!(cin>>a)) {
        cout<<"Exiting"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `if(!(cin>>a)) {` condition and just write `cout<<"You sir, Just Entered: "<<a<<endl;`, it outputs. Otherwise, currently, it doesn't output on (n+1)th input. See this image:
[image]

Comment: Why `#include <stdio.h>`? You're not using anything from it, and even if you were it should be `#include <cstdio>`.

Comment: @FredLarson Nevermind :)

Comment: If you want line-oriented input, I'd prefer to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(!(cin>>a)) {` is catching your next input (e.g. 2, 4, 6 ,8).

Then, it doesn't go inside the `if` statement because of the negation `!`

It doesn't display your second input because you do not print `a` after your second `cin`

Comment: Obviously that doesn't go as it isn't true. `if(!(cin>>a)) {` will be true when user enters a non-integer. But I'm entering integers (2, 4, 6) then why doesn't it show?

Comment: @user2513722 You never print the `a` from the `if(!(cin>>a))`.

Answer (score 1):

You're catching input twice per iteration : once in the `while`'s conditions, and a second time in the `if`'s condition. Thus, only one in two inputs get printed. That's because even if the `if`'s condition fails, it has already read by then.

Your while loop already does the check : it won't iterate if the user enters a non-number. Your fixed code is simply :

```
int main() {
    int a;
    while(cin>>a) {
        cout<<"You sir, Just Entered: "<<a<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Exiting"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Then how do I check for a non-integer input?

Comment: @user2513722: See my comment on your question. `std::stoi` will throw an exception on non-integer input.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check for non-integer input this will do.

```
int a;
while(cin >> a)
{
    cout << "Sir you entered: " << a <<endl;
}

cout << "Exiting"
     <<endl;
```

the checking is done automatically in the `while loop` because the input yields `true` if it is valid (integer in your case) this allows further inputs. if the input isn't valid, the program leaves the loop and the `exiting` message is displayed.